# How to change the traffic flow direction of an edge in SUMO?

Tags: simulation, sumo, transport

Consider a simple network file with 2 edges (1, 2) [[edge example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SJP0.jpg)] and the flow direction is from (1) to (2). I want to find a way to reverse the direction of flow using NETEDIT i.e. (2) to (1).

P.S. I want to find a way to do this using NETEDIT because I am editing a 100mb network data and it would be impossible for me to change the edge direction individually.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into select mode and select all the edges you want to revert. Then right click on an edge and select Edge operations-> reverse edge. For reverting a single edge you can skip the selection step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for the late response!